# Remove Line in a WP array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I've an Array (wordpress) and would like to remove or add some parts. I don't know if some of my needs are possible and how to do it.

These are my needs: Remove [LineRoot] but keep all [line] (just move to parent in order to have all [Line] at the same level than  [LineRoot] )

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [Order] => 679
           [LivraisonPrenom] => Joe
           [LineRoot] => Array
               (
                   [Line] => Array
                       (
                           [0] => Array
                               (
                                   [ll] => hh
                                   [Id] => 20
                                   [SKU] => A104
                                   [Quantity] => 1
                               )

                       )

                    [Line] => Array
                       (
                           [0] => Array
                               (
                                   [ll] => hh
                                   [Id] => 22
                                   [SKU] => A105
                                   [Quantity] => 1
                               )

                       )

               )

           [Meta-LangueBL] => 
           [CheckoutAddOns] => Array
               (
                   [CheckoutAddOn] => Array
                       (
                           [0] => Array
                               (
                                   [ID] => 2
                                   [Name] => Livraison
                                   [Cost] => -48.33
                               )

                       )

               )

       )

)
```

Comment: Your example array uses the key `Line` multiple times inside the `LineRoot` array - which is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of PHP functions that can help you

***[unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)***

***[array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)***

***[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)***

***[array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)***

Good luck :)

Comment: Just share what you have done, and we will help you improve it :)

Comment: i succeed with everything using UNSET, the only problem is for LINEROOT

Comment: 1- save it in a variable ($tmp) | 2- unset the index from the array | 3- push the variable  ($tmp) to the array

Comment: very sorry...i don't follow you...
I don't even know how to add something before [Order] => 679 actually

Comment: use [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)